# Client print 'Undefined' messag when i send json info from the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

When I click "ajaxsend" button, the result shows "undefined" on the console.

how can I check that function res.json is working fine?

app.js

```
var express = require('express')
var app = express()
var bodyParser = require('body-parser')

app.listen(3000, function() {
console.log("start!! express server on port 3000");
});

app.use(express.static('public'))
app.use(bodyParser.json())
app.use(bodyParser.urlencoded({extended:true}))
app.set('view engine', 'ejs')

app.post ('/ajax_send_email', function(req, res){
console.log(req.body.email)
var responseData = {'result':'ok','email':req.body.email}
console.log(responseData)
res.json(responseData)
});
```

form.html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta charset="uft-8">
    <title>email form</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form action="/email_post" method="post">
      email : <input type="text" name="email"><br/>
      submit <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <button class="ajaxsend">ajaxsend</button>

    <div class="result"></div>

    <script>
      document.querySelector('.ajaxsend').addEventListener('click',function(){
        var inputdata = document.forms[0].elements[0].value;
        sendAjax('http://127.0.0.1:3000/ajax_send_email',inputdata);
      })

      function sendAjax(url, data){
        var data = {'email' : data};
        data = JSON.stringify(data);

        var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
        xhr.open('POST', url);
        xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', "application/json");
        xhr.send(data);

        xhr.addEventListener('load', function() {
          console.log(xhr.reponseText);
        });
      }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

I expect console shows "{result:ok, email:content in input text "email"}
but the actual output is "undefined".

Comment: Do `console.log(xhr)` instead and debug on the console the entire `xhr` object to check its status.

Comment: You are only sending a value....not key/value. Inspect the actual request in browser dev tools network and see for yourself exactly what is sent

Comment: @JorgeFuentesGonzález Thank you sir, when I check the entire xhr, I can see the contents in column "ResponseText". it turned out I wrote "reponseText" instead of "responseTest". I save my time because of you. thanks and have a nice day!

Comment: @charlietfl Thanks for your comment. now I know how to debug on the console and realized the problem is my finger not a computer.. Thanks!

Comment: try accessing xhr.response. To be sure the response is coming from backend, you can check Chrome Tools, "Network" Tab and filter by XHR, you can see the request and the response.

Comment: @EuidoLEE glad that you made it on your own. You are getting skills and that's important for a developer ^^